# Merge two boot partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have Windows dual-boot with KDE Neon, and I can boot to each OS easily. But there are two boot partitions on my PC, though I set up for one when I install neon. I mount `/boot` into `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, and it contains both neon and the old windows (does not work) boot files. But when I boot into windows, it boots from `/dev/sda2`, which was created after troubleshooting boot options on windows. So can I merge them into one partition, `/dev/nvme0n1p1`?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like your nvme0n1p1 got changed from ESP - efi system partition with esp flag to bios_grub which is only for old BIOS boot of grub. Change those flags with gparted and you may need to then reinstall grub in UEFI mode & repair Windows boot loader. Do not confuse a /boot partition (Linux format) with an ESP (FAT32 format). If you need more details. Use ppa version with Ubuntu live installer.
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Hi @oldfred, and thanks for your help! I tried Boot Repair and here is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SzWRGM2kJj/

Comment: It still shows nvme0n1p1 as bios_grub. You must first use gparted and change that back to esp,boot flags, not bios_grub flag. Then rerun Boot-Repair as it does not show anything in a bios_grub partition.Your Neon UEFI entry is trying to use the ESP nvme0n1p1, but as bios_grub probably cannot use it.

Comment: I changed nvme0n101 to boot, esp, but I still can't boot into neon, it stucks on grub command screen.

Comment: Here is the paste bin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cgqHCRqsHD/

Comment: You need Internet for Boot-Repair to download new copy of grub for a total reinstall of grub. You also show grub.cfg in sda1 which is NTFS. You never install grub to a partition. Report did not show fstab. Do you have /etc/fstab in your install. If from live installer you have to mount / to see install, and then /mountpoint/etc/fstab, otherwise you get fstab of live installer.

Comment: Hi @oldfred, I can't understand much about your words. Sorry about that, and the boot repair still didn't help. 
Yes, I have /etc/fstab in the install. Here is the paste bin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QJDxjPQb3K/

Comment: See line 26: "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount." You need fast start up/hibernation off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation LIne 46: "No nvme0n1p5/boot/efi/efi/ ubuntu/mint folder"  Not sure if fixed, but still not showing fstab. This site is a question & answer site for Ubuntu. Neon is not an offical flavor of Ubuntu so you should ask in ubuntu forums other OS or stack exchange's Unix & Linux site.